# Rails: callback to prevent deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I've got a `before_destroy` callback that looks like this:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :documents, through: :publications

  def document_check
    if documents.exists?
      errors[:documents] << 'cannot exist'
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

The test looks like this:

```
describe '#document_check' do
  let(:document) { create(:document) }
  let(:component) { create(:component) }

  context 'with documents' do
    before do
      document.components << component
    end
    specify { expect(component.errors).to include(:document, 'cannot exist') }
    specify { expect(component.document_check).to eq true }
  end

  context 'without documents' do
    before do
      document.components = []
    end
    specify { expect(component.document_check).to eq false }
  end
end
```

I want it to raise the error if a component is in a document, but I can't seem to be able to write it correctly. The second test passes, the first doesn't:

```
 Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[:document, "cannot exist"]
   +[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which model you have `document_check` method ? What's the association you made between `Component` and `Document` ?

Comment: Sorry, `document_check` is in `Component` and it's a `has_many :through` relationship.

Comment: mention those all in your post,

Comment: Mention the associations between those 2 models..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the callback:

```
def document_check
  return unless documents.present?
  errors.add(:article, 'in use cannot be deleted')
  false
end
```

And here's the passing test for it.

```
describe '#document_check' do
  let(:subject)   { create(:component) }
  let(:document)  { create(:document) }
  let(:count)     { Component.size }

  before do
    document.components << subject
    subject.send :document_check
  end

  context 'with documents raises error' do
    specify do
      expect(subject.errors[:article]).to be_present
    end
  end

  context 'with documents raises correct error' do
    specify do
      expect(subject.errors[:article]).to include(
        'in use cannot be deleted')
    end
  end

  context 'with documents prevents deletion' do
    specify do
      expect { subject.destroy }.to_not change(Component, :count)
    end
  end
end
```

Took ages but it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

How is `document_check` being invoked? If manually (as you're 2nd tests seem to suggest) then you also need to invoke it for the first specify.

That is:

```
specify { component.document_check; expect(component.errors).to include(:document, 'cannot exist') }
```

That's horrible syntax, but you need to invoke the method before you can check the errors on it.